# Mac Host Virtualbox pixelation problem installing 16.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, virtualbox

I try to install either 32- or 64-bit 16.04LTS variations into Virtualbox on Mac host, and in both scenarios I cannot get past a wall of pixelated orange, pink, and black letters in long horizontal lines of apparent-giberish.

My problem is similar to the one listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747760/pixelated-ubuntu-virtualbox-on-windows-host), but none of the information provided there was helpful.

I have an old Macbook Pro, "Mid-2010" (2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 4GB 1067MHz DDR3 RAM, NVIDIA GeFORCE 320M w/ 256MB), upon which I am trying to run a Virtualbox installation of 16.04 LTS. I have had the same problem under all variations of system settings in VB, including changing the graphics settings to force or disallow 2D and 3D Acceleration.

I get through most of the early installation process just fine, but I inevitably end up on the pixelated screen. Thoughts?

Comment: UPDATE: I thought, perhaps, the pixelated screen might be related to part of the installation process, which required only time. I have run the VB machine all night and there was no change.

Comment: UPDATE 2: I am going to try other Linux variants to see if the problem is Ubuntu side or Virtualbox side. To that end, I tried installing Kubuntu 16.04.01 LTS and the pixelation problem occurred again, but with different colors and non-letter symbols. Next test will be a non-ubuntu fork.

Comment: UPDATE 3: Well, I was able to get through some of the installation process for Arch Linux without the pixelation problem. I can't actually figure out how to install it, so I'm not sure whether the problem was avoided, but I was able to get further in the process than I was with Ubuntu. Next step will be to try an older LTS version of Ubuntu.

Comment: UPDATE 4: I was able to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS no problem.